# Pine script returns "Syntax error at input 'strategy.long'."

Tags: pine-script, cryptocurrency

I've been trying to make a new simple strategy based on Stoch RSI and it was successful with this simple code

```
strategy("Long Strategy", overlay=true)
length = input.int(10, minval=1)
OverBought = input(85)
OverSold = input(5)
smoothK = 3
smoothD = 3
k = ta.sma(ta.stoch(close, high, low, length), smoothK)
d = ta.sma(k, smoothD)
b = ta.crossover(k,OverSold)
s = ta.crossunder(d,OverBought)

strategy.entry("Buy", strategy.long, when=(b and k > OverSold), comment="Buy")
strategy.close("Buy", when=(s and d < OverBought), comment="Sell")
```

But I wanted to edit it so that the strategy.close would be fulfilled only when above entry price. So, I edited the code, and I've been trying to find what's wrong with line 17 but I can't seem to.

The error says "line 17: Syntax error at input 'strategy.long'."

The code after editing is as follows:

```
strategy("Stoch. RSI", format=format.price, overlay=true)
length = input.int(10, minval=1)
OverBought = input(85)
OverSold = input(5)
smoothK = 3
smoothD = 3

k = ta.sma(ta.stoch(close, high, low, length), smoothK)
d = ta.sma(k, smoothD)
b = ta.crossover(k,OverSold)
s = ta.crossunder(d,OverBought)

var price = 0.0
if (b and k > OverSold) and strategy.position_size == 0
    price := close`
    strategy.entry(id="buy", strategy.long , comment="Buy")

if (s and d < OverBought) and (price > close)
    strategy.close(id="buy", comment="Sell")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var price = 0.0
if (b and k > OverSold) and strategy.position_size == 0
    price := close
    strategy.entry("buy", strategy.long, comment="Buy")
```

I removed the "id=" and it worked.

Comment: Thanks a lot !! 
code doesn't do the job but at least it's working now